# How to use pivot_table or unstack to create new data frame

Tags: python, pivot

I am very new to Python, so please do help me. I have a data frame as below:
[image]

and I want to unstack/pivot it to below:
[image]

I tried different methods, but I am not getting the desired result.

I first tried `groupby` with only 2 values for trial, but this doesn't work for what I want and it fills with `NaN`:

```
newdf = df.groupby(['ACCIDENT_NO', 'SEX'])['Age_Group'].value_counts().unstack()
```

I also tried `pivot_table`:

```
new_1 = new_df.pivot_table(index=['ACCIDENT_NO'], columns= [ 'SEX','Age_Group'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```

This at least fills the zero but here SEX becomes the main columns and the age groups are subdivided under it. I dont care about any subdivisions or anything ...I just want to unstack the categories as different columns as shown in the desired image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one-liner using `get_dummies` and `groupby`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=df.columns[1:], prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby('ACCIDENT_NO', as_index=False).sum()
```

And now printing `df` would return the desired result.

Comment: Oh yes ...tried it....it works to unfurl the categories, but now each accident_no is further repeated.  Each observation of the dataframe is related to 1 person in the accident and hence the accident _no has multiple entries depending on the number of people in that accident. I just want the final dataframe to have the 3 unique accident_no observations and all the counts added up as shown in the above desired image.

Comment: @Wendy Ohh forgot about that, edited my answer, added a `groupby`, should work now!